# How to detect JPanel child component paint event?

Tags: java, jpanel, paint

I have a JPanel where I place components in it. I need to get notified every time when a sub component (even nested) is repainted. Is there an event for it that I can register when a component is added to the JPanel?

My purpose is to draw a scroll bar on the right and bottom edges of the JPanel but when the sub component is redrawn, it overlaps the scroll bars and makes a part of scroll bar invisible. I want to redraw the scroll bar when a component refreshes its view so it stays behind the scroll bar.

To make it a little bit more clear, this two are the screenshots of the UI.

[image: When components overlay the scroll bar]
[image: When scroll bar overlays the components]

The first image is incorrect but this happens only if I hover the components with the mouse. Otherwise, it's looking good. The image on the right is when the container is loaded. I want the components always appear behind the scroll bar but I just cannot detect when a specific component is repainted.

Comment: you can add a `ComponentListener` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html - this Listener will notify when components have been resized, hidden/shown und moved

Comment: @MartinFrank True Martin. But repainting does not fall in any of those events. I've tried using that.

Comment: how comes that your component isn't inside of the scroll pane's view port?

Comment: honestly i think it would be better to add all components into the view port, see `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html`

Comment: @MartinFrank This is not a ScrollPane component. I am using `JPanel`. I extend the `paintComponent()` method and draw the scroll bar myself.

Comment: what's the trigger to repaint your components?

Comment: @MartinFrank Nothing. I override the `paintComponent` method and swing handles when to call that method. I do not explicitly call it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151043/discussion-between-martin-frank-and-omerhalit).

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter similar problem like this,

I've found the answer within Swing's own painting mechanism. If you want to receive component paint events from a container's child, override `isPaintingOrigin()` method.

```
@Override
protected boolean isPaintingOrigin() {
    return true;
}
```

Only this will be sufficient and painting event will be called by the underlying container.